# Deleted reCaptcha and cannot login to drupal website

Tags: drupal, recaptcha

I installed reCaptcha in the Drupal 7 module in hopes that it would work on the contact form, but it never did. So I did a really dumb thing and deleted the reCaptcha from Google and forgetting that connection to it was in the module.

It turns out that the reCaptcha did work but only on the admin login screen.  Now that I am locked out, does anyone have a really brilliant idea for someone who made a really bad move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer and I want to post it in case anyone else runs into a problem with any module in Drupal, not just with reCaptcha.

The main steps I used were found on this website: [Disabling or enabling a module](https://www.drupal.org/node/157632)

All I did was make a backup of the db.  Determined what the module name was that I was needing to disable:

SELECT name,status FROM system WHERE type='module' AND status='1'

Then change the status to '0' using of the actual module name I needed to disable:

UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='module_name'

At this point I thought it was done, but because Drupal keeps a cached copy of it enabled in the db you still have to delete the cache:

DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid='system_list'